# Why is my data getting associated with wrong column in mysql db?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have two tables connected with a many to many relationship using a composite key:

Table1

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "user_name")
        private String userName;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;

        private String password;

        private String authorization;

        @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "user",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<UserProduct> userProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "user",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
        private List<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

Table2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int price;

    private double mass;

    private double alcohol;

    private String picture;

    private int amount;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserProduct> userProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "orders",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Table with composite key

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_product")
public class UserProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserProductId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("productId")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "amount_of_new_products")
    private int amountOfNewProducts;
```

When I make a REST call to UserProduct table so i can update the product value using this payload:

```
{
    "user": 4,
    "product": 2,
    "amountOfNewProducts": 32
}
```

it writes the information depending on what is the user id and not the product id. For this payload it would write in like this:

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Grimbergen Blanche",
        "price": 132,
        "mass": 0.33,
        "alcohol": 6.0,
        "picture": "https://i.imgur.com/qIq1OrC.png",
        "amount": 502,
        "userProducts": [],
        "orderProducts": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Grimbergen Blonde",
        "price": 132,
        "mass": 0.33,
        "alcohol": 6.7,
        "picture": "https://i.imgur.com/OnioHd5.png",
        "amount": 435,
        "userProducts": [
            {
                "id": {
                    "productId": 2,
                    "userId": 4
                },
                "product": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Lav Premium",
                    "price": 73,
                    "mass": 0.33,
                    "alcohol": 4.9,
                    "picture": "https://i.imgur.com/T3gCAOE.png",
                    "amount": 1862,
                    "userProducts": [],
                    "orderProducts": []
                },
                "amountOfNewProducts": 32
            }
        ],
        "orderProducts": []
    },
```

So basically even though i passed in 2 as product id the information will be written in product with id 4 just because the users id is 4. Any kind of a clue where I might me messing up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix `mappedBy = "user"` in `Product` entity. It must be `"product"`, like this:

```java
@OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserProduct> userProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also check that you have correct `@JoinColumn` in `UserProductId` (ufortunately, you didn't put code for it to the question).